# How can I get an internal representation out of protoc?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I want to generate ReST documentation from my .proto definitions. I understand I can do this by writing a C++ plugin for protoc but that's too time-consuming for my current situation. Is there a way to make protoc output a parsed representation of the definitions with comments still included?

I'm using protobuf 3.

Comment: One feature that comes close to what you're looking for is the reflection API, which allows you to programmatically inspect your message definitions. Unfortunately this will not give you any access to comments, though. If you want to go in this direction you could try writing your documentation in the form of [custom options](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#options) in your `.proto` file, but this could be a bit awkward.

Answer (score 4):

Plugins don't need to be implemented in C++ -- they can be in any language. A [plugin](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/other#plugins) is a program that reads a [`CodeGeneratorRequest`](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.proto#L57) on standard input and then writes a [`CodeGeneratorResponse`](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.proto#L81) to standard output.

Alternatively, you can also use `protoc --include_source_info --descriptor_set_out=FILENAME` to generate a [`FileDescriptorSet`](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto#L55). Note, though, that this contains somewhat less information than `CodeGeneratorRequest`.

Information about comments can be found in [`FileDescriptorProto.source_code_info`](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto#L84), which has type [`SourceCodeInfo`](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto#L648). (Note that `--descriptor_set_out` strips this information unless you also use `--include_source_info`.)